# How do you randomly assign text values to groups in equal parts?

Tags: excel, vba

I have about 6K rows of data divided into 70 non-equal groups. Each of the groups should have 2 creativities, randomly assigned, 50% of each.

E.g. If group A is made of 100 rows (observations), 50 of them should have creativity1 and 50 of them should have creativity2 - an unequal split in case of odd numbers (101 rows, 51 creativity1 and 50 creativity2).

```vb
Sub Soggetti()

Dim wsPost As Worksheet
Set wsPost = Sheets("test")

Dim lRow As Integer
lRow = wsPost.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'last row of dataset

Dim nFree As Integer
nFree = Range("B2:B" & Rows.Count).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Row 'first empty cell in relevant column

Dim Creativity(1 To 2) As String

Creativity(1) = "ROOMMATES15"
Creativity(2) = "FAMILY15"

For X = nFree To lRow
    wsPost.Range("B" & X).Value = Creativity(Application.RandBetween(LBound(Creativity), UBound(Creativity))) 
Next

End Sub
```

This runs, but I do not know how to enforce the equal split of the two creativities within each group.

What comes out is something like
[image: Resulting Dataset]

Note the summary count in the pivot.

I would like a 7/8 split for channel A and a 9/9 split for channel B.

Comment: Please show us some sample data and your expected output. Reading [repro] will help you to improve your question.

Comment: Beyond a shared point with Ike, where mock-data or data is needed, there are infinite possibilities for what you're referring.  You want an equal split... you could loop down your list appending 1, 2, 1, 2, as you go, you could split your data and append half with 1 and half with 2... the list goes on.  More info is the key here, since this isn't answerable in the way this format is intending... one *objective* answer to resolve the issue.

Comment: You pick randomly `RandBetween` one of those `Creativity(1)` and `Creativity(2)`. Statistically you get a 50/50 distribution but what you actually get if you do this many times is a gaussian distribution. That's why you sometimes get other results than 50/50 (which is just the most likely of all distributions). There also may be the case of 100 `Creativity(1)` and 0 `Creativity(2)` as an extreme (just not so likely).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick.

Maybe is not the most technical solution, but it works.

**Updated to consider Channels:**

```
Sub Soggetti()

Dim wsPost As Worksheet
Set wsPost = Sheets("test")

Dim lRow As Integer
lRow = wsPost.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'last row of dataset

Dim nFree As Integer
nFree = Range("B2:B" & Rows.Count).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Row 'first empty cell in relevant column

Dim Creativity(1 To 2) As String

Creativity(1) = "ROOMMATES15"
Creativity(2) = "FAMILY15"

Dim FinalValue As String
Dim counter1G1 As Long, counter2G1 As Long
Dim counter1G2 As Long, counter2G2 As Long
Dim CurrentGroup As String, Group1 As String, Group2 As String
Dim Group1Count As Long, Group2Count As Long

Group1 = "Channel A"
Group2 = "Channel B"

Group1Count = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(wsPost.Range("A2:A" & lRow), Group1)
Group2Count = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(wsPost.Range("A2:A" & lRow), Group2)

For x = nFree To lRow
    
  CurrentGroup = wsPost.Range("A" & x).Value
  FinalValue = Creativity(Application.RandBetween(LBound(Creativity), UBound(Creativity)))
  
  Select Case CurrentGroup
    Case Group1
    
        If FinalValue = Creativity(1) Then
          counter1G1 = counter1G1 + 1
        Else
          counter2G1 = counter2G1 + 1
        End If
        
        If FinalValue = Creativity(1) And counter1G1 > (Group1Count / 2) Then
          FinalValue = Creativity(2)
        ElseIf FinalValue = Creativity(2) And counter2G1 > (Group1Count / 2) Then
          FinalValue = Creativity(1)
        End If
        
    Case Group2
    
        If FinalValue = Creativity(1) Then
          counter1G2 = counter1G2 + 1
        Else
          counter2G2 = counter2G2 + 1
        End If
        
        If FinalValue = Creativity(1) And counter1G2 > (Group2Count / 2) Then
          FinalValue = Creativity(2)
        ElseIf FinalValue = Creativity(2) And counter2G2 > (Group2Count / 2) Then
          FinalValue = Creativity(1)
        End If
  End Select
  
  wsPost.Range("B" & x).Value = FinalValue
    
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, Alex - however, this doesn't seem to work for me, as it still doesn't provide an equal split between the two creativities. Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: Well, it seems that I was missing something. I didnt take into consideration the channels. My answer is updated now to include the channels. It should work as expected now.